Closed form of $f(n) = \prod_{m=2}^{n-1}( e^{\pi i n/m} - e^{-\pi i n/m})$
For context, I am not a mathematician, but I like to do explore some math concepts a couple of times a year. I have been playing with an idea for the past few years or so and a while back I asked this question. I understand now how the product of the denominator m in the exponent of the function
$$\prod_{m=2}^{n-1} e^{\pi i n/m}$$
can be simplified using the Harmonic number, but I feel as though that relationship is lost when the equation is a product of differences of exponents with the denominator m in the function.
The function I am now working with is:
$$f(n) = \prod_{m=2}^{n-1} (e^{\pi i n/m} - e^{-\pi i n/m})$$
Is there any way to represent this product in closed form, or a way to approximate this product?
I have been looking into trigonometric identities and Euler's formula as well as the Harmonic number, but seem to be at a loss. Any help would be appreciated.

Note that $f(n)\neq 0$ iff $n$ is a prime number. In general, $f(n)=(2{\rm i})^{n - 2} \prod_{m = 2}^{n - 1} {\sin \left( {\frac{{\pi n}}{m}} \right)} $, but it seems there is no simple closed form for this product.
